# WPF. Закрытие окна при потере фокуса

Tags: c#, wpf

В WPF приложении есть небольшая информационная форма, которая вызывается с основной. По задумке на этой информационной форме должен быть стандартный крестик для закрытия, а так же форма должна закрываться сама при потере фокуса. Использую для этого Window_Deactivated.

```
private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

При потере фокуса все работает как надо, но при закрытии формы через крестик выпадает исключение:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Во время закрытия окна нельзя
>   установить для Visibility значение Visible или вызвать Show,
>   ShowDialog, Close или WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle.'

Можно ли как-то в Deactivated отловить, что форма уже закрывается, чтобы не кидать повторное закрытие и не вызывать исключение?

Comment: Добавьте флаг в `Window_Closing`, чтобы игнорировать `Window_Deactivated` событие. Либо, если `Window_Deactivated` происходит раньше `Window_Closing` сделайте кастомную кнопку в обработчике которой устанавливайте флан на запрет работы кода из `Window_Deactivated` события.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно, выставляйте флаг и проверяйте его:

```
bool isClosing = false;

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);
    isClosing = true;
    // Возможно, правильнее isClosing = !e.Cancel;
    //  если выдаете запрос на закрытие или что-то типа того
}

private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isClosing) Close();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, с попытками изучить кучу мудреных паттернов совершенно перестают приходить такие простые мысли. Единственное что в WPF в Window_Closing нельзя вызывать base - уходить в рекурсию. Просто выставить флаг - тогда все работает как надо.

Comment: Ну у меня не подписчик на событие `Window_Closing`, а перегрузка метода базового класса (`override` видите же). Но вообще можно, конечно, сделать как вы написали :)